# Realizar un Blackup de la base de datos a la sd

Tags: android, sqlite

Como puedo hacer un backup de la base de datos a la tarjeta sd en android studio. tengo la base de datos realizada, pero no se como implementar una copia de seguridad y que quede en la sd

Answer (score 0):

Puedes implementar el siguiente método:

```
public void copiarDB(String nombreDB) {
    try {
        File sD = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File datos = Environment.getDataDirectory();
        String rutaDbActual = "//data//" + getPackageName() + "//databases//" + nombreDB;
        String rutaDbCopia = "copiadb.db";

        if (sD.canWrite()) {
            File dbActual = new File(datos, rutaDbActual);
            File dbCopia = new File(sD, rutaDbCopia);
            if (dbActual.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(dbActual).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(dbCopia).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e);
    }
}
```

Necesitaras tener el permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` en la aplicación

Comment: Ese metodo lo implemento en la misma clase de la bd o en el main?

Comment: Es indiferente, si quieres usarlo tal y como esta, colocalo en el main